# Unique resource identifiers for S3 blobs

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, minio

Is there any "standard" way to uniquely identify an S3 blob using a single string?

There are multiple services that support the S3 protocol: AWS, Minio, GCS.

Usually, to access an S3 blob, you must provide endpoint (+region), bucket and key. The 's3://' URIs seem to only contain bucket and key. Is there any standard that also includes the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

At least for GCS there is no standard on how you should name the objects that are uploaded to the bucket, they just need to follow the format rules [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming).

Nevertheless, as mentioned in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Afh-70WAk6g), there are some tricks that you can follow in order to have a better performance on the read/write operations in a bucket through object naming.

If you have a bit more time, you can also check [this other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC_4qO-BIjc) which goes more in depth on how GCS works as well as performance an reliability tips.